# Fast animation with big images

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage

I have a task to make simple animation for iPad2 like here:http://www.subaru.jp/legacy/b4/index2.html

User can simply slide to left and right and object visually rotates by it's vertical axis. I think simpliest way to do this is to use a UIImage or CCSprite from cocos2d, set array with images and to change images depends on touches. The size of images planned to be 1024x768(full screen)and at least 15-20 images per second for smoother animation. Question is: is it possible to do this really smooth this way? What is the real limit for iPad2 for such a thing. And if it's behind the bounds how can I realize this behavior other way?

Comment: May be you can use video and play it in AVPlayerLayer?

Comment: But how can I link a video to touches and can it be fast enough to react to touches? I mean that user can slide slow or fast, and animation speed need to match exactly with touch speed.

Comment: You dont need to link a video to touches. place the video in a layer, and add an empty layer above it  which is touch enabled. Do your touch processing inside that layer, a shadow to the one with the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's run the math:

15 times 1024x768 images per second. If you use 4096x4096 texture atlases you can put them all into a single texture atlas. That covers 1 second.

That means you need to load another texture atlas every second. At most you can have 2-3 such texture atlases in memory (conservatively each uses 64 MB memory).

Really the only way to make this feasible is to use .PVR.CCZ texture atlases to increase load times and reduce memory usage. You'd still have to load/unload texture atlases frequently (within a few seconds). So you should do a test how fast loading the 4k .PVR.CCZ texture is and whether that will impact speed.

If that's too slow (which I suspect it will be) you'll have to use 1024x1024 .pvr.ccz textures (single frames) and keep caching 4 or more of them ahead of time using the CCTextureCache async methods (and uncache the texture you're currently replacing) so that the loading of new textures occurs in the background and doesn't affect animation speed.

Since this is about rotation, you'd have to ensure that at least one, better two frames to either direction are in the cache. Since rotation can happen at various speeds, the user might still experience delays regardless.

You should further reduce color bit depth of the textures as much as possible until it affects image quality too much.

If you apply every trick in the book, I'm sure it's doable. But it's not going to be as simple as "play animation" and be done with it. If that's what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

I've did something like this before, but using a JS library with UIWebView control, the library name is [UIZE](http://www.uize.com/), check this [example](http://www.uize.com/examples/3d-rotation-viewer.html). I've used it with around 100 image with size 1024 × 655 and it's so smooth.

Download the library from the size, organize the folders as the following:

- rotation3d

  - example

    - 3d-rotation-viewer.html
- images

  - Images files
- js

  - The library files.

In your objective-C class, use the following code to load the html page in the UIWebView:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  pathForResource:@"3d-rotation-viewer"
                  ofType:@"html"
                  inDirectory:@"rotation3d/example" ];

NSURL *urls = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSString *theAbsoluteURLString = [urls absoluteString];

NSString *queryStrings = @"?param1=something";//Parameters to pass to your html page

NSString *absoluteURLwithQueryString = [theAbsoluteURLString stringByAppendingString: queryStrings];  

NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString: absoluteURLwithQueryString];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)10.0 ];

[webViews loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Thanks! But I never made something like this, so can you explain a little bit more? How can I use this library in iOS project?